# GeoTIFF not covering base map in QGIS3

Tags: openstreetmap, qgis, geotiff

I have a situation where my geoTIFF map is not covering the entire OpenStreetMap basemap. Please advise...

Top image: GeoTIFF
Bottom image: Dhows where the tiff is not reaching the top of the basemap.

Thank you in advanced

L

[image: GeoTIFF]

[image: But within QGIS the geoTIFF is not covering the whole basemap.]

Answer (score 0):

I am a noob to GIS,

Required reprojecting the geoTIFF to match Open Street Map.

Here's how to do so...
https://tilemill-project.github.io/tilemill/docs/guides/reprojecting-geotiff/

L